# Is there any way to refresh intellisense without rebuild project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#, intellisense

F# Visual Studio 2013

For example, if you add a new function to a different file, you need to rebuild the project so this new function appears in the intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both files are in the same project, all you need to do is save the file. If it's in another project, then you have to rebuild.